# MySQL query works on backup DB but not on original where it fails with errno: 150

Tags: mysql

I import a backup of my MySQL DB on my machine (OS X 10.13.6) and I run this script:

```
ALTER TABLE user_activity_data
ADD FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES Article(id);
```

All is fine: foreign key is added.

I run **the same** script on the original machine (Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)) and the script fails with error message:

```
errno: 150
```

The **types of the two columns are exactly the same**: int(11)

How is this possible? It's a backup, so it's the same DB. It's true that it's two different versions of MySQL... but they should clearly be compatible.

---

This is the version of MySQL on which the script fails:

```
+-----------------+
| 5.5.60-0+deb8u1 |
+-----------------+
```

And the version on which it succeeds:

```
+-----------+
| 5.7.22    |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20166573/2240141

Comment: they both can be int(11) if one is "unsigned" then they are different types. Check if both columns are singed/unsigned.

Comment: Both are unsigned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to ensure that your foreign key has the exact same type as the primary key.

MySQL 5.5 was probably a bit more forgiving, while MySQL 5.7 is a bit stricter. Consider using the same version on both.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because it is useful to clarify in my question that the types of the two columns are exactly the same. But this does not solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Uhah! Found it, but was nasty one :(

It seems that,

- **on Debian the table names are case sensitive and on OS X they are not.**

Thus the problem was that the object of the `REFERENCES` clause should have been `article(id)` instead of `Article(id)`.